# How can I ask this user a question about their answer if I don't have enough rep to post comments?

Tags: discussion, private-messaging, contact

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565280/vs-2010-fails-debugging-httpexception-invalid-file-name-for-file-monitoring-in) I had a question for the last answer provided by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256727/dmitry-dzygin) (Dmitry Dzygin).

I'd like to ask more about his answer but I cannot comment on his answer. I also see that I cannot contact him via his profile.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn, "ask this user... their answer"? The noun and pronoun don't agree.

Comment: @doubleDown whats wrong with it? Looks like the correct usage of the singular they

Comment: @doubleDown Grammar nazi.

Comment: @double It's the singular 'they' used to specify the gender indefinite.

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn, by golly you're absolutely right. Learned something new today. Though the [wikipedia page on 'singular they'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) did say, "debate continues about its acceptability"

Answer (score 11):

I recommend that you to set out and earn 50 rep then see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

To earn the additional 28 rep you could:

- Receive 6 up-votes on a question @ 5 rep each.
- Receive 3 up-votes on an answer @ 10 rep each.
- Have 2 answers accepted by the OP @ 15 rep each.
- Have 14 suggested edits accepted @ 2 rep each.
- Accept answers on 14 of your own questions @ 2 rep each

Comment: I do not think you need to @reply if you are commenting on the user's own post (either a question or answer). The 50 rep threshold is still accurate, though.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Good point, though sometimes I use the "@reply" to direct a comment to an OP when there are multiple users commenting on a post.

Comment: That's funny had to put "@reply" in quotes so that the system wouldn't think that I was trying to reply to multiple users

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps ask a question, putting in detail of your query and make reference to the answer in question.  Be sure to be detailed in your question, particularly with details on what exactly you are trying to do, what you have done so far and any and all details of any research on that topic that relate to the question.

Comment: I would do this before trying to get the 50 rep and commenting. Get the 50 rep anyway just because rep is cool, but if you post a new question you'll get a much quicker, crowdsourced answer than waiting on a single individual to come back and give you a reply, which would be less beneficial to future visitors since it won't bump the question.

Answer (score 7):

There are two approaches:

1. Gain the reputation necessary to comment.

   You can do this by posting good questions and answers, or by suggesting good edits to posts which need improvement.
2. Post a new question with all of the detail needed to explain your request.

   This question should not be directed at the original answerer (who may or may not be available) but can include a link to that answer. However, your question should provide enough information to stand on its own, whether or not the original answer exists.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, you *don't* contact people. There's no "private message" facility in the Stack Exchange site. You can earn enough rep to leave a comment on a question/answer or you can start your own question, but there's no guarantee that the person you're trying to contact will see or reply to these. On the other hand someone else who can give you an equally good solution/explanation to whatever query you have could step up to the plate instead.